# What should RenderingComponent declare?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

Developing a Pong game to learn DirectX 11.  Does this Sprite/Model class get declared in the RenderingComponent class for a ECS design?  Additionally, sprite doesn't make sense for a 3D game but what if I wanted to swap out 2D and make it 3D; should this actually be a Renderer instance?  Examples given below.

```
class Entity
{
private:
  Components* components;  
};

class Component
{
// base class stuff here
};

class RenderingComponent : public Component
{
private:
Sprite* sprite;   // (Q) SHOULD THIS BE A SPRITE OR MODEL OR RENDERER CLASS
                  // (if I want to swap out for 3d?)
};

class Sprite      // (Q) MAYBE THIS SHOULD BE A MODEL OR RENDERER CLASS INSTEAD

}
```

Comment: Not enough context. Clarify please.

Comment: Should renderingcomponent declare a sprite or model? Basically where will the drawing abstraction go?

Comment: _"Basically where will the drawing abstraction go?"_ Rather to the Sprite IMO.